# delayed reaction to NSURLSession response

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having an odd problem with my Swift application where a seemingly sequential sequence of events is resulting in unsequential output. I have a button click operation that looks like the following (where `self.indicator` is UIActivityIndicatorView and `self.errorBox` is a UILabel):

```
func onSigninClick(sender: UIButton!) {

    let url = NSURL_REMOVED_FROM_EXAMPLE
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    var data = [
        "u": self.usernameBox.text,
        "p": self.passwordBox.text
    ]
    var err: NSError?
    request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(data, options: nil, error: &err)

    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
    self.indicator.startAnimating()
    self.errorBox.text = ""

    session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in

        self.indicator.stopAnimating()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false

        if error != nil {
            Logger.warn("Sign In Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            let json = Parser.parseJson(data) // returns SwiftyJSON object
            Logger.info("Received response: \(json.stringValue)")
            if json["result"].boolValue {
                // success
                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(Account.loginNotification, object: self)
            } else {
                // additional errors within message
                for error in json["errors"]["details"].arrayValue {
                    let code = error["code"].intValue
                    let message = error["message"].stringValue
                    Logger.error("Internal error \(code): \(message)")

                    if code == 1001 {
                        self.errorBox.text = "You must specify username and password"
                    } else if code == 1002 {
                        self.errorBox.text = "Incorrect username or password"
                    } else {
                        self.errorBox.text = "Unknown error, error code: \(code)"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

I send the request and receive the response. When the request is sent a spinning indicator appears and the intent is for it to disappear as soon as the message is received.

The problem is that the request makes it back way before the UI "reacts" to it. In my logic above you can see the log messages. I also see `UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible` icon disappear as soon as the message appears in the logs. Yet the indicator (which is told to stop animating right before) continues to spin for another 5 seconds or so. Same applies to the error message, which only appears about 5 seconds later. I also have `self.indicator.hidesWhenStopped = true` defined in my loadView.

I can't figure out what's happening. Why does neither the indicator nor the error box update until much later on? Even if the redraw is asynchronous, it shouldn't take 5 seconds to occur.

Also, I tried timing it, the delay seems to vary as well. Sometimes 5 seconds, sometimes as long as 30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The completion handler provided to the `dataWithRequest:completionHandler:` method will be called on the `delegateQueue` of the `NSURLSession`. By default this queue is a serial `NSOperationQueue` created for the `NSURLSession`, i.e. not the main thread. Even then, I'm not sure iOS provides any behaviour guarantees for UI updates ever occurring if they were initiated outside the main thread.

In iOS, UI operations must happen on the main thread. When you tell your activity indicator to cease animating nothing will happen until the main thread notices the update.

Try setting the `delegateQueue` of your `NSURLSession` to the main queue, or alternatively you can try using `dispatch_async` to the main thread for just the UI updates:

```
self.indicator.stopAnimating()
UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
```

---

Edit showing the `delegateQueue` approach:

While the `delegateQueue` property is read-only, you can set it when creating the `NSURLSession` with the specialized init method:

```
init(configuration configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration,
     delegate delegate: NSURLSessionDelegate?,
     delegateQueue queue: NSOperationQueue?)
```

Comment: Thanks! delegateQueue for NSURLSession is read-only so that option was out, but dispatch_async worked.

Comment: The delegateQueue property is read-only, but you can set it using the specialized init method.